# Are there some free Acumatica tenant snapshots available to download and use?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I would like to develop integrations with Acumatica ERP (version 2019 R2) for a BI Application which extracts data from a local Acumatica instance and loads it into an external destination.
In order to test this properly, I need a reasonable amount of data.

The documentation of Acumatica states that a tenant can be created from a snapshot (Refer to: https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/(W(20))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=57406416-cf4c-4f91-874e-489d680e8ef0 ).

Are there existing snapshots for tenants which developers can use to test their integrations as entering the data manually is a lot of work?

Comment: SalesDemo is the recommended data set for development, an empty instance should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the site through the configurator you can state the initial data, which will be inserted when the instance is created. I would suggest to select "SalesDemo" and a number of documents and settings would be ready for you to use once the site is created.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tidy6.png)

Comment: The data is coming from XML file in the Acumatica directory, default path: C:\Program Files\Acumatica ERP\Database\Data